# Dojo 1.17.3 takes a few second to render the page

Tags: dojo, render

I just upgrade Dojo from 1.10.4 to 1.17.3. On 1.10 the page renders without any issue. However, running Dojo 1.17.3 I see this funky behavior during page rendering.

[image]

After a few seconds the page gets render correctly. Does any one faced/facing this problem? Is there a way to fix it. I get no error during the rendering, so not sure what would be the root cause.
This is that the page looks like after rendering.
[image]